# Django Admin, All the contents of my table are not being displayed & Inline Issue

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-admin

Attached below is the models.py I used for my project,

I've attached the photos of the issue as well.

**Issue 1**

For some reason, all the contents of the tables are not being displayed.
In the first table, first content goes missing.
In the Second table, First and the second contents go missing

**Issue 2**

The Inline function doesn't work. I tried going through the documentation and several youtube videos to find out how to handle the situation but it didn't help much.

**Issue 3**

For the bug table, When I select the project name, How do I ensure that only the people I added to that project table are allowed to be selected?

**Issue 4**

Is there a way to extract the email ID from the Users page and and when I choose the name of the user in the Project page, the email Id will be automatically filled it?

Same way, In the issues page, when I choose the user, the email Id will be auto entered.

[image]
[image]

**MODELS.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Project Manager', 'Project Manager'),
       ('Technician', 'Technician'),
       ('Tester', 'Tester')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Work Assigned', 'Work Assigned'),
       ('Work in Progress', 'Work in Progress'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Completed', 'Completed')
   )
   Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Project_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Admin_Name_users+')
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_1_users+')
   Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Project_Manager_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_1_users+')
   Technician_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Technician_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_2_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Technician_3_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Tester_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Tester_1_users+')
   Tester_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Example@gmail.com')
   Additional_User_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='User.Ad_1_users+', blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Finish_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

   class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       fieldsets = (
           (None, {
               'fields': ('Project_Name','Project_Description','Admin_Name','Admin_Mail_ID','Project_Manager_1','Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID',
'Technician_1','Technician_1_Mail_ID','Tester_1','Tester_1_Mail_ID','Status_of_the_project','Created','Finish_Date','Supporting_Documents',
)
           }),
           ('Add More Users', {
               'classes': ('collapse',),
               'fields': ('Project_Manager_2','Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID','Technician_2','Technician_2_Mail_ID',
                          'Technician_3','Technician_3_Mail_ID','Additional_User_1','Additional_User_1_Type',
                          'Additional_User_1_Mail_ID','Additional_User_2','Additional_User_2_Type','Additional_User_2_Mail_ID',
                          'Additional_User_3','Additional_User_3_Type','Additional_User_3_Mail_ID'),
           }),
       )

   def __str__(self):
       return self.Project_Name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "List Of Projects"

class Bug(models.Model):

   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Unassigned', 'Unassigned'),
       ('Assigned', 'Assigned'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Tested', 'tested'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Bug', 'Bug'),
       ('Issue', 'Issue'),
       ('Enhancement', 'Enhancement'),
       ('Not an issue or bug', 'Not an issue or bug'),
       ('Fixed', 'Fixed')
   )
   Project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Issue_Title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Situation_Type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Basic_Description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Detailed_Description = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Status = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE)
   Assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Assigned_to_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reporters_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Reported_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Deadline_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents_By_Reporter = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Project_Managers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Project_Manager = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Technicians_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Technician = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
   Testers_Comment = models.TextField(default='The Description, here.')
   Supporting_Documents_by_Tester = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return '{} ({})  [{}]'.format(self.Project, self.Situation_Type, self.Status, self.Issue_Title)


   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
       if self.id:
           user=self.Assigned_to
           self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID=user.email
       send_mail(self.Admin_Mail_ID, ass=self.Assigned_to_Mail_ID)
       super(Bug, self).save()

   class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Projects Tasks/Issues"




def send_mail(admin,ass):
    email=EmailMessage('Changes made to Task','Changes have been made to one of your Task reports and we hereby request you to have a look at it at the earliest.', to=[admin,ass])
    email.send()
```

I've also attached the admin.py file as well.
**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Bug, Project
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
admin.site.register(LogEntry)


# Register your models here.


class BugDisplay(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Project', 'Status', 'Basic_Description', 'Assigned_to', 'Created', 'Updated', 'Issue_Title')
    list_filter = ('Status', 'Assigned_to', 'Project')
    search_fields = ('Reporters_Mail_ID', 'Reported_by', 'Basic_Description',)



admin.site.register(Bug, BugDisplay)


# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectDisplay(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Project_Name','Admin_Name', 'Project_Manager_1', 'Status_of_the_project')
    list_filter = ('Admin_Name', 'Status_of_the_project')
    search_fields = ('Project_Name', 'Project_Description', 'Admin_Name', 'Admin_Mail_ID', 'Project_Manager_1 '
                        'Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID', 'Project_Manager_2 ', 'Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID',
                        'Technician_1',
                        'Technician_1_Mail_ID', 'Technician_2', 'Technician_2_Mail_ID', 'Technician_3',
                        'Technician_3_Mail_ID', 'Tester_1', 'Tester_1_Mail_ID', 'Additional_User_1', 'Additional_User_1_Type',
                        'Additional_User_1_Mail_ID', 'Additional_User_2', 'Additional_User_2_Type', 'Additional_User_2_Mail_ID',
                        'Additional_User_3', 'Additional_User_3_Type', 'Additional_User_3_Mail_ID', 'Status_of_the_project', 'Created',
                        'Finish_Date', 'Supporting_Documents')
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your question please provide your admin inline class (referring to issue 2) and please elaborate for issue 1 and provide more details.

Regarding issue 2 you can override appropriate field using [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey.). You can provide your custom queryset(by applying your filter conditions) to the foreign key field.

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'your_field_name':
        kwargs["queryset"] = your_custom_queryset_based_on_conditions

    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

For issue 4, you want email Id to be auto filled based on user selection. This can be achieved using custom **javascript**.

Another way could be that, you do not show email field and while saving the record from project/issue admin you automatically fetch email id from users table and assign it to the object and save it.
You may have a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), to customize while saving the object from admin panel.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    email = your_method_to_find_email_for_user(obj.user_field) 
    obj.email_field = email
    super().save_model(request,obj,form,change)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me out! 
As for Issue 1, Under the projects table, I've made 2 entries. Of the 2, only the 2nd entry, is displayed. the 1st entry goes missing. As you can see, database contains 2 items, but only 1 is being displayed, Meaning I cant edit/delete the 1st entry.

Comment: Similarly, In the issues table, there are supposed to be 4 entries, of which only 2 entries are being displayed.

The 1st in the Project table, and 1st and 2nd entry in Issues table are not being displayed.

Looking forward for your inputs about the issue

Comment: Ok, this usually happens when we have a foreign key pointing to some non existent data.In your Bug model you have Project and Assigned_to as foreign keys, pointing to Project and User. Make sure that the data exists in those tables and is not invalid. That is why count (in Bug admin) is correct but it is not able to pull the record due to data inconsistency.

Comment: That makes sense, But what do you think would be the quickest way for me to delete all the contents of the table without having to fix the code that I posted in the question?

PS, I added another table and changed the columns, but for me to implement the code, I first have to delete all the contents of the table. But I cant, because the rows dont get displayed.

Comment: You can delete the data manually via SQL query at the database. You might disable foreign key checks and after deleting data from required tables, enable it again. Doing this, won't give you foreign key errors.